# Ansible Docker Module from OSX

Tags: docker, ansible

I am trying to use the Ansible Docker module at the moment but I am currently encountering this error when I try to run my playbook -

```
NameError: global name 'DEFAULT_DOCKER_API_VERSION' is not defined
```

I found an official bug regarding this at https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/1792.

I have tried the workaround by installing docker-py but have had no joy as of yet.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong? I'm trying to run my Playbook from my local OSX host that connects to AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation we managed to get it to work by using -

```
name: Install Docker PY
pip: name=docker-py==1.1.0
```

In our .yml file

Comment: You can also have 1.2.3 now.
pip: name=docker-py version=1.2.3

Comment: you might also need to add pip: shell: "curl -sSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python"

Answer (score 0):

pip is a package manager for python and installs with it. So what you want to do is installing python.

On OS X I recommend you to first install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), which is a package manager for OS X. The command to install Homebrew is

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

After Homebrew is installed you can install python and along with it pip with

```
brew install python
```

Comment: Thanks, I've installed pip and the error "Failed to find required executable pip" has now resolved itself. However, I'm now receiving the first error again regarding the docker api verison. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, I have not worked with the docker module yet. But please update your question or create a new one to solve this new problem.

Comment: Sure no problem, I've updated my question as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is related to the absence of pip or docker-py library.

I have this in my docker ansible role.

```
- name: install the required packages
  apt: pkg={{ item }} state=present update_cache=yes
  with_items:
   - python-pip

- name: Install docker-py as a workaround for Ansible issue
  pip: name=docker-py version=1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; `-e use_tls=encrypt`

- I'm using the newest `dockerpy==1.5.0`
- `~/.bash_profile` I have `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` which will run

  ```
  export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
  export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
  export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/meyers/.docker/machine/machines/default"
  export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
  ```

Now that your environment is setup let me tell you the fix. The docker module needs the parameter `tls=encrypt`. You can supply it to each invocation of the docker module in your Ansible task or you can set it "globally" via `-e use_tls=encrypt` or in your playbook:

```
    - hosts: all
      vars:
        use_tls: 'encrypt'
      tasks:
        ...
```